# CSS Styling after changing the elements places

Tags: jquery, css

I have a simple menu with `<ul>`s. 
I would like to change the elements places and keep the style as it is(I should change the css that belong to the elements that the change occurred in it).
Here's my menu: http://jsfiddle.net/EPvGf/24/
Code,
CSS:

```
ul#menu { margin:0; padding:0; list-style-type:none;text-align: center; }
ul#menu li { position:relative; float:left; border-bottom:4px solid #efefef; margin-right: 10px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 5px;display: inline-block;}
ul#menu .current { border-bottom:4px solid #3d496a;}
ul#menu li:hover { border-bottom:4px solid #3d496a;}
ul#menu li a { padding:2px 2px; text-decoration:none; font:bold 8px Verdana, Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif; color:#68759c;}
ul#menu li a:hover { color:#8895b8; border:none; }
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#" data-id="div1">Description</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-id="div2">Shipping and payment</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-id="div3">Returns</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-id="div4">Feedback</a></li>
</ul>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#menu').on('click', 'a', function () {
        $('.current').not($(this).closest('li').addClass('current')).removeClass('current');
    }).find('a:first').click();
});
```

What I'm trying to change is a VERY SIMPLE change in the HTML code, just placing the `<a>` before the `<li>`(it's after it), so it would be like that:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <a href="#" data-id="div1"><li>Description</li></a>
    <a href="#" data-id="div2"><li>Shipping and payment</li></a>
    <a href="#" data-id="div3"><li>Returns</li></a>
    <a href="#" data-id="div4"><li>Feedback</li></a>
</ul>
```

but stay have the same styles.. here's what I tried, but it doesn't work 100%: http://jsfiddle.net/EPvGf/25/

[image]

[image]

Comment: A `<ul>` with `<a>` children is not valid HTML. Your `<a>` tags should be inside your `<li>` tags. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: that when I click the `<li>` it does the same thing as when I click the word that inside the `<li>`

Comment: so the `<a>` comes to both of the `<li>` and the word not only for the word as it is in the first example

Comment: Why are you wrapping the <li> in an <a>? According to the HTML specs an <li>'s parent must be an <ol>, <ul> or <menu> (documented here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/li.html#li-context).

Comment: I'm not sure that this is legal even in HTML5, but since you want it to look the same, and presumably operate in the same way, why do you want to change it?

Comment: @MattRohland here's what I want, as you can see in this picture: 
http://i.imgur.com/Ci2DHLG.png
I can click on the word but not on the line(that is the `<li>`) and all what I want that to be able to click on the line(the `<li`) as in the picture here: 
http://i.imgur.com/Z0fPdLY.png
Simply enough :|

Comment: @MikeW here's what I want, as you can see in this picture: 
http://i.imgur.com/Ci2DHLG.png
I can click on the word but not on the line(that is the `<li>`) and all what I want that to be able to click on the line(the `<li`) as in the picture here: 
http://i.imgur.com/Z0fPdLY.png
Simply enough :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest keeping your `<a>` tags inside your `<li>` tags, as the other way around is not valid HTML.

However, in order to make the entire `<li>` function as a link, you can move padding to the anchor instead of the `<li`>. That way, the anchor will expand the `<li>`, essentially filling the `<li`> with anchor.

```
ul#menu li {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
ul#menu li a {
    border-bottom:4px solid #efefef;
    padding:2px 2px 7px 2px;
    text-decoration:none;
    font:bold 8px Verdana, Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color:#68759c;
}  
ul#menu li a:hover {
    color:#8895b8;
    border-bottom:4px solid #3d496a;
}
```

Also, as shown in my example, jQuery may not be necessary. I suggest using a class to indicate which item is selected.

```
ul#menu li.selected a {
    border-bottom:4px solid #3d496a;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EPvGf/39/

---

**EDIT:**

If you really need/want to use jQuery, you should be able to use the code you had.
I had just named my "current" class as "selected" instead.
Updated fiddle below.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#menu').on('click', 'a', function () {
           $('.current').not($(this).closest('li').addClass('current')).removeClass('current');
    }).find('a:first').click();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EPvGf/38/

Comment: You didn't looked at the jquery, I think you have to change something in the jquery too so when I click the link its style change to the`.current` style, can you do it? also the line(`<li>`) should active the link also, if you can fix these both problems everything will be perfect, thank you

Comment: I was suggesting that jQuery may not be necessary for this application. However, I have edited my answer for jQuery usage.

Comment: This might just be nit-picking, but I'd normally add the display:block to the li rather than the anchor, since that's really the block-level element here.

Comment: Perfect code really perfect only one thing and I will give 20 reputation, can you center the menu as it was? it's align is left I want it to be in the center and that's it

Comment: @MikeW I see what you mean. In fact, the display settings are not necessary at all since the <a> is going to be larger than the (empty) <li>. Thanks for the hint. http://jsfiddle.net/EPvGf/34/

Comment: Can you please look at my question about centering the menu?

Comment: I have edited my answer to center the menu again, as well as to remove unnecessary display properties.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the behavior you're looking for can be accomplished with valid html.

An LI's immediate parent must be a UL, OL or MENU element (see: w3.org/TR/html-markup/li.html#li-context)).

**HTML**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#menu').on('click', 'a', function () {
        // Unassign .current from all <li>s in the #menu
        $('#menu').find('a').removeClass('current')

        // Assign .current to clicked on <li>
        $(this).addClass('current');
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
a:hover {
    color: #0000FF;
}
ul#menu {
    margin:10;
    padding-left:13px;
    list-style-type:none;
    text-align: center;
}
ul#menu li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
}
ul#menu li a{
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom:10px solid #efefef;
    margin-right: 15px;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    font:bold 12px Verdana, Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color:#68759c;
}
ul#menu li a.current {
    border-color: #3d496a;
}
ul#menu li a:hover {
    border-color: #3d496a;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EPvGf/40/

Comment: Clicking the bottom border does not activate the link, which I think is what the OP is going for. The entire LI should be clickable, not just the text.

Comment: I don't want it to be just clickable(I can make it through css(`cursor: pointer`) but I want it to active the link too.
I think the other person's answer is kindly good, only one thing incomplete, the jquery using if you can do it please try to, if not thank you very much for your helping

Comment: Wonderful code, only one thing lost :| the jquery? it doesn't work, it doesn't set the li's style as ".current", why?